# fixing error in implementing async/await in for loop(forEach of array) js

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, async-await

while running this code i get output of

```
1
3
2
```

my intented output is

```
1
2
3
```

```js
const test = [1, 2, 3]
test.forEach(async (i) => {
   if (i === 2) {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
   }
   console.log(i);
 })
```

how do i make the print statement to wait 3s if i === 2
if you can  pls explain too :)

Comment: yes, How did I miss that question? :(. sry for wasting your time

Comment: No worries, but very detailed discussion in the duplicate. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `.forEach` to execute sequentially because the Promise returned to the `forEach` function is ignored. You have to use `for...of` loop.

Here's an example:

```js
const test = [1, 2, 3];

(async function () {
    for (let i of test) {
        if (i === 2) {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
        }
        console.log(i)
    }
}());
```